# VB ArcGIS 9.3 Field Calculator

Tags: vba

I'm trying to join one column into another.  one is "acct id" and the other is "taxid number".  Acct is from one county whereas the tax is from another, so there are blanks in the number of parcels/rows.  I did it before last week and I had it written down how to do this.

What I need to do is move `'acct id'` into the `'taxid'` column. I remember having `" "` as part of the vb script.  What are the steps involved as I keep getting a blank field when I attempt it.

Comment: what is the data format? shape, mdb, pgdb, fgdb? BTW you would not need the vb code block to complete this in field calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would select all the blanks in the taxid column:

1. Open your Attribute Table.
2. Choose the Options button on the lower right section of the Attribute table and then choose "Select by Attributes..." in the drop down menu.
3. Setup the SQL expression something like: [taxid] IS NULL (for Personal Geodatabase) or "taxid" IS NULL (for shape file). If the blanks doesn't contain a NULL value you can select the blanks this way [taxid] = ' ' . The syntax depends on your Field format.
4. When your blanks are selected you can make a Field Calculation in the taxid field.
5. Your expression should simply state this: [acct_id]. Remember to keep the "Calculate selected records only" option enabled.

If this doesn't work, my guess is, that the taxid and the acct_id have different Fields formats. If that is the case you will need to add a new String Field and "copy" your taxid and acct_id values to this new field.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank You, I had part of it, but the select by attributes is what was missing.  This VBA is all new to me so I'm learning, trial by error method.  Once I begin seeing how it works, then is when I start picking it up naturally.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to move the values in the 'acct id' into the 'taxid' Field, it should be as simple as:

```
[acct_id]
```

*(The field names cannot have a space, so I do not think that 'acct id' is the field name, it should be the field Alias)*

If on the other hand, you want to concatinate the strings from both 'acct id' & 'taxid' into a third field, it can be:

```
[acct_id] & [taxid]
```

if you want a space inbetween them, it hsould be:

```
[acct_id] & " " & [taxid]
```